# Plai multiple values

Tags: scheme, racket, plai

my task is to make this to test to run:

```
(test (run "{+ {2 1} {3 4}}") '(5 6 4 5))
(test (run "{+ {- {+ 1 3} 2} {10 -10}}") '(12 -8))
```

The source code i have so far looks like that

```
#lang plai

(require (for-syntax racket/base) racket/match racket/list racket/string
         (only-in mzlib/string read-from-string-all))

;; build a regexp that matches restricted character expressions, can use only
;; {}s for lists, and limited strings that use '...' (normal racket escapes
;; like \n, and '' for a single ')
(define good-char "(?:[ \t\r\na-zA-Z0-9_{}!?*/<=>:+-]|[.][.][.])")
;; this would make it awkward for students to use \" for strings
;; (define good-string "\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"")
(define good-string "[^\"\\']*(?:''[^\"\\']*)*")
(define expr-re
  (regexp (string-append "^"
                         good-char"*"
                         "(?:'"good-string"'"good-char"*)*"
                         "$")))
(define string-re
  (regexp (string-append "'("good-string")'")))

(define (string->sexpr str)
  (unless (string? str)
    (error 'string->sexpr "expects argument of type <string>"))
    (unless (regexp-match expr-re str)
      (error 'string->sexpr "syntax error (bad contents)"))
    (let ([sexprs (read-from-string-all
                 (regexp-replace*
                  "''" (regexp-replace* string-re str "\"\\1\"") "'"))])
    (if (= 1 (length sexprs))
      (car sexprs)
      (error 'string->sexpr "bad syntax (multiple expressions)"))))

(test/exn (string->sexpr 1) "expects argument of type <string>")
(test/exn (string->sexpr ".") "syntax error (bad contents)")
(test/exn (string->sexpr "{} {}") "bad syntax (multiple expressions)")

;; WAE abstract syntax trees
(define-type WAE
  [num  (listof number?)]
  [add  (left WAE?) (right WAE?)]
  [sub  (left WAE?) (right WAE?)]
  [with (name symbol?) (init WAE?) (body WAE?)]
  [id   (name symbol?)])

; parse-sexpr : sexpr -> WAE
;; to convert s-expressions into WAEs
(define (parse-sexpr sexp)
  (match sexp
    [(? number?) (num sexp)]
    [(list '+ l r) (add (parse-sexpr l) (parse-sexpr r))]
    [(list '- l r) (sub (parse-sexpr l) (parse-sexpr r))]
    [(list 'with (list x i) b) (with x (parse-sexpr i) (parse-sexpr b))]
    [(? symbol?) (id sexp)]
    [else (error 'parse "bad syntax: ~a" sexp)]))
```

parses a string containing a WAE expression to a WAE AST
    (define (parse str)
      (parse-sexpr (string->sexpr str)))

substitutes the second argument with the third argument in the first argument, as per the rules of substitution; the resulting expression contains no free instances of the second argument

```
(define (subst expr from to)
  (type-case WAE expr
    [num (n)   expr]
    [add (l r) (add (subst l from to) (subst r from to))]
    [sub (l r) (sub (subst l from to) (subst r from to))]
    [id (name) (if (symbol=? name from) (num to) expr)]
    [with (bound-id named-expr bound-body)
          (with bound-id
                (subst named-expr from to)
                (if (symbol=? bound-id from)
                    bound-body
                    (subst bound-body from to)))]))
```

evaluates WAE expressions by reducing them to numbers

```
(define (eval expr)
  (type-case WAE expr
    [num (n) n]
    [add (l r) (+ (eval l) (eval r))]
    [sub (l r) (- (eval l) (eval r))]
    [with (bound-id named-expr bound-body)
          (eval (subst bound-body
                       bound-id
                       (eval named-expr)))]
    [id (name) (error 'eval "free identifier: ~s" name)]))

; run : string -> listof number
;; evaluate a WAE program contained in a string
(define (run str)
  (eval (parse str)))
```

bin-op : (number number -> number) (listof number or number) (listof number or number) -> (listof number))
applies a binary numeric function on all combinations of numbers from the two input lists or numbers, and return the list of all of the results

```
(define (bin-op op ls rs)
  (define (helper l rs)
    ;; f : number -> number
    (define (f n) (op l n))
    (map f rs))
  (if (null? ls)
    null
    (append (helper (first ls) rs) (bin-op op (rest ls) rs))))
```

Can someone please give me an idea how to change my functions to make the tests above work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the smallest example of an expression that doesn't work?

Comment: The rule `[(? number?) (num sexp)]` looks suspious. A `num` seems to represent a list of numbers, so presumably the pattern on the left needs match a list of numbers (now it matches a single number).